# Why is $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb Z)$ supposed to lie over $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb F_1)$ rather than the other way around?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, field-with-one-element

$\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$I understand that one major motivation for the [field with one element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element) is supposed to be that there should be a map $\Spec(\mathbb Z) \to \Spec(\mathbb F_1)$, which has been implicated in a hypothetical proof of the Riemann hypothesis. I'm puzzled by this, though because for every actual finite field $\mathbb F_q$ the map goes in the opposite direction, $\Spec(\mathbb F_q) \to \Spec(\mathbb Z)$. So I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Why is there expected to be a map $\Spec(\mathbb Z) \to \Spec(\mathbb F_1)$, rather than in the opposite direction as for all actual finite fields? Is there additionally expected to be a map in the usual direction, $\Spec(\mathbb F_1) \to \Spec( \mathbb Z)$?

Comment: I think the argument comes the comparision with function fields, say for instance $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$. Then the structure morphism is $\mathbb{F}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p[t]$. Hence the global field lies "above" the finite field. Hope this helps.

Comment: The idea is that in the actual category of rings, $\mathbb Z$ is the initial object (so in the category of affine schemes its spectrum is the final object or "universal base"). But this is inconvenient for a number of reasons, so the hope is to come up with some (or really, some other category that has a) more convenient universal base called $\operatorname{Spec}({\mathbb F}_1)$.

Comment: Specifically, if $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbf Z$ is supposed to be a curve, then it better be a curve over something (hopefully a field). That something does not exist, but if it did, we'd call it $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbf F_1$.

Comment: I should add that many working arithmetic geometers do not take this analogy too seriously. There is indeed a lot of work towards building things that behave like $\mathbf F_1$ in *certain* (but not all) ways, but it seems very far removed from proving things like the Riemann hypothesis. If you want to transfer the function field argument to number fields, what you really need is a 'product' $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbf Z\times\operatorname{Spec}\mathbf Z$ (over $\mathbf F_1$). Scholze's diamonds are an attempt at capturing this, but only in a neighbourhood of a diagonal point $(p,p)$.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I get that but I suppose what I’m saying is that if there were something for $Spec Z$ to live over I would _not_ call it $F_1$ because it behaves very differently from a finite field…

Comment: @TimCampion Fair enough. It gets even trippier if you think about finite fields themselves living over $\mathbf F_1$. Is that supposed to be an algebraic extension? But then the Galois theory of $\mathbf F_1$ should see this, which does not seem to be the case. It's also not a transcendental extension, as finite fields allegedly have absolute transcendence degree 0 (whereas number fields have absolute transcendence degree 1, whatever that means). I think everybody agrees that $\mathbf F_1$ is not a field.

Comment: That "everybody agrees that F_1 is not a field" reminds me of a footnote in Hobsbawm's The Age of Extremes in which he notes that what puzzles the physicists is not whether quarks, which no one has seen, exist or not but why they are never alone ;-)

Comment: Alain Connes and many other extremelly brillant mathematicians have worked for more than 20 years on notions revolving around $\mathbb{F}^1$ and they all stood by that name. And you, in a sunday afternoon post, would suggest that finally it is not the right name because you discovered "it does look like it's not a field"?

Comment: @Libli Maybe to make further progress we need to abandon the metaphor of “field”.  Anyway, this is forum to ask questions.  There should be no “sacred taboos” here.  If the OP wants to know why a morphism is one direction instead of the other, that is not an insult (explicit or implicit) of experts in that field.

Comment: Links to a number of attempts at understanding F-un: [Soulé](http://www.ams.org/distribution/mmj/vol4-1-2004/soule.pdf), [Toën & Vaquie](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509684), [Connes & Consani](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.2926) ([+more](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.2024)), [Deitmar](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1389017411), [Durov](http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2030), [Borger](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.3146), [Lorscheid](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.0083), [Manin](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.1564). And [a comparison](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.0069) between some of these. I must have missed some.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I'm not sure how useful this might be, but I have a folder with some  references (139 PDFs) for $\mathbb{F}_1$, and I figured doing a `tree` on it might end up being useful as a quick list of references, despite its formatting. Here it is: [Link](https://pastebin.com/p0UjZqkT)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what does "there should be a map" mean? Is there some additional condition that everybody knows, except me?

Comment: As explained above by R. van Dobben de Bruyn, Scholze has a very good candidate for the completion of $\mathrm {Spec}\mathbb Z\times \mathrm {Spec}\mathbb Z$ along $(p,p)$. 
But according to one of his recent talks, he hopes being able to define  $\mathrm {Spec}\mathbb Z\times \mathrm {Spec}\mathbb Z$ itself, in the framework of analytic stacks which he is currently developing with Clausen -- both are currently giving a wonderful course on it, available online.

Comment: @Dirk The additional condition is that one must choose a formalism in which $Spec \mathbb F_1$ is well-defined. There are many or none of these depending on your perspective.

Comment: @TimCampion Sorry, but I don't get it. If there could be a map, then $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_1)$ is a set and if its a set then there are the trivial constant maps, for example. I seem to miss a lot here…

Comment: @Dirk 'map' is probably understood as 'morphism in a suitable category', the main problem being that there is no agreed upon definition of what this category is. It is only an analogy, trying to port aspects of the proof of the Riemann hypothesis for curves (Weil) or varieties (Deligne) over finite fields to the classical Riemann hypothesis for $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbf Z$.

Comment: Thanks @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, that's actually helpful.

Comment: @AntoineDucros Do you remember which lecture they mention the hope to define $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})\times\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ in the framework of analytic stacks? I haven't been following their course, but wanted to check out this specific part now (and most likely the entire course later in the future)

Comment: @Emily This was in this talk (which was not part of the ongoing curse, it was more informal, one or two months before), close to the end of the talk. 
https://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/node/12330

Comment: @AntoineDucros Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

*(I'm not sure this qualifies as an answer or an extended comment, because I don't have any deep knowledge in the matter, but I hope this can at least help clear some possible confusion.)*

It seems to me that there are (at least) two different reasons to hypothesize the existence of some kind of “field with one element”, which may or may not be the same in both cases:

The first reason comes from the classification of the semisimple algebraic groups $G$: the Weyl group $W(G)$ of $G$ behaves in many ways similarly to the group of points of $G$ over a field that should have $1$-element (inter alia, $\# G(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is a polynomial in $q$, and $\# W(G)$ is the value at $1$ of that polynomial multiplied by $(q-1)$ to the appropriate power so it is nonzero; but also, the Weyl group has much structure, like parabolic subgroups and such, that is analogous to the $G(k)$ for $k$ a field).

So the idea there is that $G$ has *more structure* than being just an algebraic group over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$: this means that (just like an algebraic variety $X$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has *more structure* than the algebraic variety $X_{\mathbb{C}} := X \times_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Q}} \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}$ that it defines) we can forget this extra structure by moving up to $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$, but by doing so we are discarding something.  So $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ should be thought of as being above $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_1$, and by forgetting the combinatorial structure (root system, Weyl group, etc.) we move from $G$ over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_1$ to $G$ over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ (or over any ring in the usual sense).

It is not clear whether $W(G)$ should be taken literally as $G(\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_1)$ in this setup, but at least it should have some connection to it: again, the idea is that $G$ lives over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_1$ and you can pull it back to $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ if you want, but you then lose the ability to compute $G(\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_1)$.

The second reason to hypothesize some kind of $\mathbb{F}_1$ comes from the analogy between function fields (of curves over finite fields) and number fields: so roughly $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ should play a role analogous to $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_q[t]$.  The main obstacle in this analogy is that $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_q[t]$ has a base field $\mathbb{F}_q$ whereas $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ does not.  So $\mathbb{F}_1$ is supposed to be that base field, and $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z} \to \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_1$ should be somewhat analogous to $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_q[t] \to \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_q$.

That second picture of $\mathbb{F}_1$ is less clear than the first (to me at least; and again, it's not clear whether the two pictures really refer to the same object), in part because it's not clear what kind of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z} \times_{\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_1} \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z} \to \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ we should get by pulling back $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z} \to \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_1$ by itself, or, relatedly, what the $\mathbb{F}_1$-points of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ should be (if this makes any kind of sense); so I can't say whether there should be a morphism $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_1 \to \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e., an $\mathbb{F}_1$-points of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$) at all or not, but the structural map is in the direction $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z} \to \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_1$.

(Still, one possible idea in this second picture is that by forgetting the $\mathbb{F}_1$-structure on $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ we lose its Archimedean place $\infty$ and associated Arakelov structure.  But it's not clear that this really refers to $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ or some kind of completion thereof, like $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_q}$ is to $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_q[t]$.)

Comment: One thing that confuses me about the $G(\mathbb F_1) = W(G)$ analogy is that, from my extremely shallow understanding, it's for split groups.  I guess that, for non-split groups, it should instead be that $G(\mathbb F_{1^n})$ is the absolute Weyl group of $G$, and perhaps $G(\mathbb F_1)$ is a relative Weyl group, or perhaps it is a form of the absolute Weyl group, whatever that means over $\mathbb F_1$, or ….  Do you know if this perspective is described anywhere (or perhaps it is just silliness)?

Comment: @LSpice I don't know, but I agree that my handwaving was too handwavy and that I should have written that $G$ was a *split* (or at least, quasi-split) algebraic group. I wouldn't dare venture write anything precise about the general case, but I agree that what you write seems highly plausible.

Comment: (I should probably also have written the word “building” somewhere in this answer, and somehow cited Tits. Ah well. )

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth mentioning that if we knew how to define $\mathbb{Z} \times_{\mathbb{F}_1}\mathbb{Z}$ and do some basic intersection on it, then the Riemann hypothesis could be proved to be true (see the work of Connes and Marcolli).